# textbox controls at run time Asp.net core using kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I programmatically add textbox controls at run time with Asp.net core using kendo UI?

( I don't want use kendo grid )

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really want(your post strongly lacks of information), but I think you might try templates:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <script id="textbox-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
   <input type="text" name="#= data.Name #" value="#= data.Value #">
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    #fields-container input {
      display: block
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fields-container"></div>
  <button>Add textbox</button>
  
  <script>
    let getValues = function getValues() {
      return {
        Name: "User[" + $('input').length + "]",
        Value: "John Doe"
      };
    };
    
    $('button').on('click', function() {
      let template = kendo.template($('#textbox-template').html()),
          dataValue = getValues(),
          templateValue = template(dataValue);
      
      $('#fields-container').append(templateValue);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/EZUZaYIy)

As you said you don't want to use grid, I imagine that you want something like kendo does in grid that is to use templates in background. You can use a template alone without any widget at all. With the snippet above you can request data form server with ajax(in the `getValues()` function precisely) or grab the data from other sources.